# Нужна функция которая принимает аргументы массив и ключ, и возвращает массив ключ

Tags: javascript, массивы, методы

Мне нужна функция которая принимает аргументы массив и ключ, и возвращает массив ключ. Пожалуйста объясните в чем проблема?

```
let litmir = [ 
{ author: 'Хэленка', title: 'Улетела сказка'},
{ author: 'Коул Кресли', title: 'Восстание Аркан'},
{ author: 'Райчел Мид', title: 'Золотая лилия'}
];

function propertyValue(array, key) {
return array.map( a => a.key );
} 

console.log(propertyValue(litmir, title) ); // Ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, ключ в функцию нужно передавать как строку, сейчас вы пытаетесь передать переменную title, которой не существует. Во-вторых изменить синтаксис обращения к ключу объекта с точки на квадратные скобки, чтобы можно было использовать переменную в качестве названия ключа

```js
let litmir = [{
    author: 'Хэленка',
    title: 'Улетела сказка'
  },
  {
    author: 'Коул Кресли',
    title: 'Восстание Аркан'
  },
  {
    author: 'Райчел Мид',
    title: 'Золотая лилия'
  }
];

function propertyValue(array, key) {
  return array.map(a => a[key]);
}

console.log(propertyValue(litmir, 'title'));
console.log(propertyValue(litmir, 'author'));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за полезный ответ )